# Root to leaf path sum = given number

Tags: c, binary-tree

How is this recursion proceeding? For the first time it will be 14-10=4 and the 
if (node->left) condition satisfies so function with node->left(node 8) and sum value(4) is called, but what is the use of the or condition in the node->left and node->right?

Say the sum given was 21 then after we recurse down finally node 3 and sum=3 is called in the node->left function, 1 is returned as sum=0 and there are no child nodes but where is 1 returned back to is it node 8 and after that do we go to node 5?

If we do node 5 doesn't return any value so how does it calculate left child of a returning 1 and it's right child not returning any value? I do not see where actually the or condition is used and why is it necessary to use it in both node->left and node->right if condition?

```
int main()
{
  int sum=14; //sum=21;

  struct node *root = newnode(10);
  root->left        = newnode(8);
  root->right       = newnode(2);
  root->left->left  = newnode(3);
  root->left->right = newnode(5);
  root->right->left = newnode(2);

  if(hasPathSum(root, sum))
   printf("There is a root-to-leaf path with sum %d", sum);
  else
   printf("There is no root-to-leaf path with sum %d", sum);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}

bool hasPathSum(struct node* node, int sum)
 {
  /* return true if we run out of tree and sum==0 */
   if (node == NULL)
   {
      return (sum == 0);
   }

   else
  {
    bool ans = 0;     
    int subSum = sum - node->data;

    if ( subSum == 0 && node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL )
     return 1;

    if(node->left)
    ans = ans || hasPathSum(node->left, subSum);
    if(node->right)
    ans = ans || hasPathSum(node->right, subSum);

    return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
if(node->left)
    ans = ans || hasPathSum(node->left, subSum);
if(node->right)
    ans = ans || hasPathSum(node->right, subSum);
```

the first "ans = ans || ..." has no function as ans is false. In the second if, ans could have been set to true by the first if, and then the hasPathSum will not be called. However, it makes for good orthogonal looking and easy to read code

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation for a detailed explanation of what is going on in your || operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
if (root->left)
  ans = hasPathSum(root->left, subSum);
if (root->right && ans ==  false)
  ans = hasPathSum(root->right, subSum);
```

instead, and also is correct.

As Paul said if ans could have been set to true by the first condition then the second conditonal and call to the recursive method is not neccessary anymore since the path in which the sum is equal to the given parameter has been found.

Answer (score -1):

```
void path(Node *root,int arr[],int end){
     if(root==NULL)return;
     arr[end++]= root->data;
     if(root->left ==NULL && root->right==NULL){
         for(int i = 0;i<end;i++){
             cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
         }
         cout<<"#";
     }
     else{
         if(root->left)path(root->left,arr,end);
         if(root->right)path(root->right,arr,end);
     }
 }
void printPaths(Node* root)
{
    int pathArr[1000];
    path(root,pathArr,0);
    cout<<endl;
}
```